# Javascript: Looping to any number with even/odd descriptions. Why does it just record the user input?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, counter, getelementbyid

I need to have the loop in this script count up to any number the user inputs.

It accurately describes the user input, but doesn't loop and count up to it.

How do I go about fixing this? Should I be coding it differently?

I am very new to javascript, and coding in general, any advice would be much appreciated!

Here is what I have so far:

```
function clickAlert2() {
  var whatNum = document.getElementById("userEnterNum").value;
  for (var i = 1; i <= whatNum; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0)  
      document.getElementById("evenOddList").innerHTML = i + ". National Gamers - EVEN <br>";
    else if (i % 2 === 1)
      document.getElementById("evenOddList").innerHTML = i + ". National Gamers - ODD <br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("evenOddList").innerHTML =` - each iteration is overwriting what the previous iteration did - you may want `+=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I understood what you want. Here is the code. Just copy and paste.

```html
<input type="text" id="userEnterNum">
<button type="button"
        onclick="clickAlert2()">Test
</button>
<div id="evenOddList"></div>
```

```js
function clickAlert2() {
  var whatNum = document.getElementById("userEnterNum").value;
  var whatNum = parseInt(whatNum);  // this will parse the string to a number
  for (var i = 1; i <= whatNum; i++) {
   if (i % 2 == 0) {
      document.getElementById("evenOddList").innerHTML += i + ". National Gamers - EVEN <br>";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("evenOddList").innerHTML += i + ". National Gamers - ODD <br>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried fitting your code to mine, but it seems to be the same issue. If it helps to visualize, this is what the <id> evenOddList should look like:
Let's say you entered 5
1. National Gamers - ODD
2. National Gamers - EVEN
3. National Gamers - ODD
4. National Gamers - EVEN
5. National Gamers - ODD

I keep getting this:
With user input of 5
5. National Gamers - ODD

Comment: So I think I didn't understand well your problem. Do you want to stack your output?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know the comment would be so jumbled up!

I want my output to count out 1 through "user input" while also describing every number as either even or odd.

Comment: Now I understood what you want. I edited my post. Get my code and Try it. What I did was: inside your if-else, as @jaromanda-X said, you were overwriting your messages each iteration. Instead of using '=' in  'document.getElementById("evenOddList").innerHTML =', you should use '+=', so you will add your previous message to the new one.

Comment: That did it! Thanks to the both of you!

Comment: Good job. But I would suggest you another way of doing this, which is more elegant. Inside your IF-ELSE, you should create <p></p>, add your content between the tag and then add to your "evenOddList" as a child Element.

Comment: You can achieve that by doing: create a text node using "var text = document.createTextNode("your text")", then create a paragraph element with "var p = document.createElement('p')", add your text in the paragraph with "p.appendChild(text)",then add your paragraph inside your "evenOddList" as a child Element with "document.getElementById("evenOddList").appendChild(p)".

Answer (score 0):

As an initial idea to try out to fix your code, try adding `alert(whatNum)` after `var whatNum = document.getElementById("userEnterNum").value;` - perhaps the element does not exist with that `id` or has a `value` different from what you expect.  Try also adding `alert(1 <= whatNum)` - it should be `true` if the `for` loop body is to ever be executed.

Please also post the corresponding HTML or HTML snippet, the user input you are testing with and the observed browser output for that user input - if any.  Also, check your browser console and post anything outputted when running this JavaScript code.  Thanks and good luck!